# How to calculate difference between datetime objects and get a time interval based on the number of days

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, intervals

I have 2 datetime columns like this:

Column 1:

```
0   2016-06-30 16:57:12.219297
1   2016-07-19 16:02:21.408984
2   2016-07-19 16:02:21.408984
3   2017-08-31 16:35:14.414915
4   2017-08-31 16:35:14.414915
5   2016-07-14 19:39:21.029636
6   2018-07-30 15:10:41.919970
7   2016-08-16 13:50:16.941665
8   2017-04-27 22:19:32.264015
9   2018-06-25 19:47:42.126527
```

Column 2:

```
0   2019-07-02 21:06:06.080788
1   2019-06-02 21:58:55.188987
2   2019-06-02 21:59:25.069153
3   2016-07-14 19:39:21.029636
4   2018-07-30 15:10:41.919970
5   2017-08-31 16:35:14.414915
6   2017-08-31 16:35:14.414915
7   2019-01-21 15:20:07.471152
8   2017-07-20 17:24:44.189102
9   2017-07-20 17:24:44.189102
```

I want to calculate the time difference between the 2 and get the results in days. Once this is done, i want to conserve those results between and interval of < 45 days and > 45 days.

How can i do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) for convert timedeltas to days and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['diff'] = (df['col2'] - df['col1']).dt.days

df1 = df[df['diff'] < 45]
df2 = df[df['diff'] > 45]
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. But if use  `df1 = df[df['diff'] < 45]
df2 = df[df['diff'] > 45]` i will not get the interval. I will get those which are above 45 and under 45, but this are the ones i want to exclude, i want to conserve the middle part. Those in the range <45, >45

Comment: @Miguel2488 - Not sure if understand, do you think `== 45` ?

Comment: no no it's ok jezrael. TYhank you, the solution you posted was good :)